# Read all files and folders on my network drive

Tags: java, parallel-processing

Let's say you have a task to read all files that are saved in some folder and process every single file. For simplicity sake let's say that all files are HTML files and you want to extract the HTML content from them.

In Java 8 there is Files.walk API that allows us to do something like that. Here is an example:

```
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("/home/you/Desktop"))) {
    paths
        .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

This sound really good if you have to process small amount of folders and files, but if you have milion of files distributed across several network drives then this process will take ages and obviously needs to be paralelised. Any ideas how to do parallelism in this case?

Comment: what needs to be parallelized, the finding of the files, or the processing?

Comment: Finding the files is bigger problem for me right now. I think I could come up with solution for data processing.

Comment: Did you try adding a `.parallel()` to your stream?

Comment: Most likely the device speed will be a bottleneck anyway. Maybe if you got a really fast network connection you could try to walk through different devices at the same time.

Comment: My idea was to first make a runner that will read all file names and file paths. This process could be paralelised for different drives. All these file locations could be then saved into DB and then make parallel job that will read files and process them.

Comment: @Thomas I didn't try with parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple general algorithm to solve your problem.

In fact the general idea when dealing with big amount of data distributed on many nodes is letting each node do the *collecting* of data and the *processing* those partial results in a single node.

Doing all the scanning from a single system is going to be hard.

To do some real optimization you cannot treat all the folder in the same way.

What you could do is to create a `Collection` of `Paths` that could be scanned in parallel.

So instead of *walking* along a single root not you could start several *walks* along several folder (possibly one for each network drive).

For this to work you need to *know* which path is a network path and which is a local one.

If you, for example have a folder where each child folder is a mounted network drive, you could easily collect all those folders and the run your *walk* in parallel for each.

I would do something similar to the following code:

```java
public class ParallelWalks {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    ExecutorService singleThreadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ParallelWalks().exec();
    }


    public ExecutorService executorSelector(Path path) {
        if(isNetworkDrive(path)) {
            return executor;
        }else {
            return singleThreadExecutor;
        }
    }


    private boolean isNetworkDrive(Path path) {
        // Here goes the logic to choose which path should go on a different
        // thread.
        return path.toString().contains("srv");
    }


    private void exec() {
        Path path = Paths.get("/home/you/Desktop");
        try (Stream<Path> files = Files.list(path)) {
            files.forEach(this::taskRunner);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Do something with the exception
        }
    }

    private void taskRunner(final Path path) {
        executorSelector(path)
            .submit(() -> doWalk(path));
    }

    private void doWalk(Path path) {
        try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(path)) {
            paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Do something with the exception
        }
    }

}
```

This way all your *local* dir will be processed sequentially, and all network drives will be processed each on his thread.

It would work only if all (or most of) your network drives share the same mount point parent.

Otherwise you should implement your own *walk* .